# Image resize on pinch

Tags: javascript

Hi all i am working on image resize and zoom on pinch using javascript. i am trying it out serching in google but i am not getting it properly i am finding it very difficult i am not much know about javascript can any one provide me a good links or examples regarding this.. thanks in advance

Comment: pinch? this is hardware specific and javascript would not able to capture more than one point

Comment: hi can any one pls help me out in this i have stucked in this

Answer (score 0):

Try with this ;)
http://hammerjs.github.io/

You can easily implement touch events with it... including pinch...